# A question on aliasing and sampling in a measurement system

Tags: voltage-measurement, sampling, aliasing

Before asking my question here is the scenario how the voltage signals are used:

Where I work some are performing data acquisition of four DC signals through four channels by a daq device at a particular sampling rate. The DC signals are coming from transducers devices measuring temperature, air pressure, force transducer ect. All of these transducers have calibration certificates which have linear calibration equations for voltage to temperature conversion as Temperature = A*Voltage + B where A and B are the slope and offset of the calibration equation. So by looking at a certificate one can say "I measure this voltage so this corresponds to this temperature" ect. After sampling and logging the data, the engineers use software like MATLAB where they can do several transforms like FFT ect.

**Here comes my question:**

Imagine an analog DC signal coming from a force transducer in a time interval as below:

[image]

And imagine the maximum frequency of interest is 50Hz.
So according to Nyquist theorem the sampling frequency should be at least 100Hz.

But if this signal has many frequency components higher than 50Hz we will be face to face with a situation called aliasing. So we will be undersampling some of the frequency components. So far this is what understand form aliasing.

And below represents this:

[image]

I encounter some tutorials which suggest anti-aliasing filters like RC low-pass filters between the transducer and the daq so that we remove high freq. components and avoid undersampling and aliasing.

1-) Do you think in my case this type of filtering is necessary if the tools like MATLAB can do post signal processing like low-pass filtering? Or an analog anti-aliasing filter is still needed?

2-) If they don't do any FFT and filtering, is there a possibility the signal's mean values or low freq. components might be affected significantly by aliasing?

3-) How can I know that if a filter is needed or not? (I know how to use a scope)

My concern is if I use a low pass filter I don't want to affect the calibration equation of the transducer.

Comment: Your understanding of aliasing seems to be correct. Whether filtering is required depends on whether the input to the ADC contains noise or undesired signals whose frequency is above the Nyquist cutoff. If the ADC input does contain such noise, then it could definitely effect mean values and low frequency components. Post-capture digital signal processing cannot remove aliased noise from the data.

Comment: "Post-capture digital signal processing cannot remove aliased noise from the data." This is the heart of the confusion I have. Is it possible to explain this in a simple way by an example or pictorially?

Comment: In this type of situation, what would be very helpful would be to start by determining the signal bandwidth first, then choosing a sample rate, then adding an anti-aliasing filter. The physical variables you are measuring have an inherent bandwidth. And the transducers also have an inherent bandwidth. Any signal content with a frequency higher than these bandwidths is noise. So you should use your anti-aliasing filter to block any such signal. And sample fast enough to capture the desired signal.

Comment: How about not using a filter but sampling with lets say 5000Hz for a signal of interest's  max freq. component is 50Hz and then post-process?

Comment: I cannot find a tutorial on these issues

Comment: Is your ADC calibrated with a certificate? If not, you already have broken the chain of certified results. So you will need to somehow validate the accuracy of the ADC anyway. So adding the filter will not create any new problem. Besides, a simple RC low-pass filter on the ADC input will have a minimal and predictable effect on the signal, provided that the R is much smaller than the input resistance of the ADC. If the frequency of interest is only 50 Hz, add a 500 Hz RC low-pass filter and sample at 5 KHz.

Comment: DAQ's ADC auto calibrates itself. My concern was if I add a passive filter would that affect the calibration equation of the transducer acting as a voltage divider? In low pass RC filter you say if I choose R small relative to input impedance of the daq it wont affect the signal much right? Sme use active filter, it seems over concern for my application.

Comment: Now Im trying to find out how an undersampled high freq. component affect the low freq freq. component. Can you help me to understand this or give me a hint where I can search. I have to explain this to others to convince them for the need for an anti-aliasing  filter.

Comment: You can design better filters in the digital domain for such low frequencies, its easier to over-sample your inputs.

Comment: @sstobbe You suggest to over sample and use digital filtering instead of an analog anti-aliasing filter?

Comment: Well you still have an analog filter on the input, but a first order filter only provides 20dB/decade of attenuation. So if you set a filter at fs/2 at 5*fs it is only attenuating tones that will alias by 1/10 (-20dB).

Comment: Why not to write a longer explanatory answer maybe with an example. Im trying to get info bit by bit this way.

Comment: Your question is a pretty broad one, try http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/3efedde4322fef19862567740067f3cc/68f14e8e26b3d101862569350069e0b9?OpenDocument, also google National Intruments topic x, as a starting point, and revise for a more specific question

Comment: More poor understanding of Nyquist

Comment: @JonRB, could you elaborate? Do you think I have a poor understanding of Nyquist, or sstrobbe, or the OP or NI?

Comment: @mkeith not you, the OP "And imagine the maximum frequency of interest is 50Hz. So according to Nyquist theorem the sampling frequency should be at least 100Hz.". Nyquist theorem didn't state that... If it was me and the frequency of interest was just 50Hz then I would sample at 500Hz.  In fact I work sample as high as possible so additional digital signal processing can be performed

Comment: @JonRB, got it. Agree.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing

Comment: if no one answers i think this question will be automatically deleted

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions in order:

1. Once the signal is aliased it's like cream in your coffee, you can't really get it back out again. If there was just one strong signal you could notch it out (losing whatever real signal happens to exist at that frequency), but generally once it's mixed in you're scuppered.
2. The signals aliasing into different frequencies should not affect the mean if everything behaves linearly **and** your averaging period does not include an undue amount of aliased very low frequency component. For example, if you had a signal that was being aliased down to 0.01Hz and took a 1 second sample, the mean could be greatly affected. Low frequency components, of course, can be directly affected.
3. Ideally the high frequency components (those above the Nyquist frequency) would be negligible. The closer you get to the Nyquist frequency the better your filter has to be. For a high accuracy measurement and a simple single or 2-pole RC frequency you might need to sample at 200 or even 2000x higher than the highest frequency of interest (that's what I came up with in a recent design).

You would want the **passband** flatness of your filter to not affect the desired signals. It may be easy to test this with a signal generator. You want the **stopband** attenuation to be such that negligible signal exists to be aliased down into your signal band. Again you can test this with a signal generator, and compare with actual signal components if you have them available (many oscilloscopes will do a crude FFT- ADC resolution is typically very low on oscilloscopes- that gives you an idea of what is going on). In between the filter rolls off if you have many decades for that to happen it is much easier. You can probably test the DC accuracy much better than you can create an accurate AC signal but if you know the DC accuracy and the passband flatness you can get a pretty good idea of what is going on.